# MSAL angular login multiple redirects

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

I'm trying to use MSALv2 for my angular 14 app. I followed the guide on [Microsoft's page for MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code)  login and logout works fine but whenever I login, I get forwarded to the login page at least 2 times and then finally to the previous route. Example:

- user is not logged in but wants to access /profile/edit/123.
- Instead they land on "local login page" with some info about the login process and why they have no access.
- On clicking login (no credentials entered), they are redirected to MS where the login is handled.
- On successful Login, they are returned to the previous route (/profile/edit/123).

All this works but on the last step, they are forwarded to the login page twice, before being routed to the actual page they had viewed before.  Here is my relevant config:

```
// app.module.ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http"; // Import 

import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';

import { MsalModule, MsalRedirectComponent, MsalGuard, MsalInterceptor } from '@azure/msal-angular'; // Import MsalInterceptor
import { InteractionType, PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';

const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE ') > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/') > -1;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatListModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MsalModule.forRoot( new PublicClientApplication({
      auth: {
        clientId: 'Enter_the_Application_Id_Here',
        authority: 'Enter_the_Cloud_Instance_Id_Here/Enter_the_Tenant_Info_Here',
        redirectUri: 'Enter_the_Redirect_Uri_Here',
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE,
      }
    }), {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
      authRequest: {
        scopes: ['user.read']
        }
    }, {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect, // MSAL Interceptor Configuration
      protectedResourceMap: new Map([ 
          ['Enter_the_Graph_Endpoint_Here/v1.0/me', ['user.read']]
      ])
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    MsalGuard
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, MsalRedirectComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```
// app-routing.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MsalGuard } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { CanActivateGuard } from './can-activate.guard';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [CanActivateGuard],
  },
  {
    path: 'profiles',
    canActivate: [CanActivateGuard],
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./profiles/profiles.module').then((m) => m.ProfilesModule),
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      initialNavigation: 'enabledNonBlocking',
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

```
// can-activate.guard.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  CanActivate,
  Router,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
} from '@angular/router';
import { MsalBroadcastService, MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { InteractionStatus } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { filter, Observable, of, switchMap } from 'rxjs';
import { LoginService } from './services/login.service';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CanActivateGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private msalService: MsalService,
    private loginService: LoginService,
    private router: Router,
    private msalBroadcastService: MsalBroadcastService
  ) {}

  canActivate(
    _route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.msalBroadcastService.inProgress$.pipe(
      filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None),
      switchMap(() => {
        if (this.msalService.instance.getAllAccounts().length > 0) {
          return of(true);
        }
        this.loginService.redirectUrl = state.url;

        return of(false);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

```
// login.service.ts
import { Inject, Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  MsalService,
  MsalBroadcastService,
  MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
  MsalGuardConfiguration,
} from '@azure/msal-angular';
import {
  AccountInfo,
  AuthenticationResult,
  InteractionStatus,
  InteractionType,
  PopupRequest,
  RedirectRequest,
  EventMessage,
  EventType,
} from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { Observable, of, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoginService implements OnInit {
  loggedIn!: boolean;
  redirectUrl: string = '';
  private readonly _destroying$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(
    @Inject(MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG) private msalGuardConfig: MsalGuardConfiguration,
    private authService: MsalService,
    private msalBroadcastService: MsalBroadcastService
  ) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$
      .pipe(
        filter((msg: EventMessage) => msg.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS)
      )
      .subscribe((result: EventMessage) => {
        console.log(result);
      });
  }

  updateLoggedInStatus() {
    this.msalBroadcastService.inProgress$
      .pipe(
        filter(
          (status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None
        ),
        takeUntil(this._destroying$)
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.setLoggedIn();
        this.checkAndSetActiveAccount();
      });
  }

  login() {
    if (this.msalGuardConfig.interactionType === InteractionType.Popup) {
      this.loginWithPopup();
    } else {
      this.loginWithRedirect();
    }
  }

  logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }

  destroy() {
    this._destroying$.next(undefined);
    this._destroying$.complete();
  }
  
  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.loggedIn;
  }

  getActiveAccount(): AccountInfo | null {
    return this.authService.instance.getActiveAccount();
  }

  private checkAndSetActiveAccount() {
    /**
     * If no active account set but there are accounts signed in, sets first account to active account
     * To use active account set here, subscribe to inProgress$ first in your component
     * Note: Basic usage demonstrated. Your app may require more complicated account selection logic
     */
    let activeAccount = this.authService.instance.getActiveAccount();

    if (
      !activeAccount &&
      this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts().length > 0
    ) {
      let accounts = this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts();
      this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(accounts[0]);
    }
  }

  private setLoggedIn() {
    this.loggedIn = this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts().length > 0;
  }

  private loginWithPopup() {
    if (this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest) {
      this.authService
        .loginPopup({ ...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest } as PopupRequest)
        .subscribe((response: AuthenticationResult) => {
          this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(response.account);
        });
    } else {
      this.authService
        .loginPopup()
        .subscribe((response: AuthenticationResult) => {
          this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(response.account);
        });
    }
  }

  private loginWithRedirect() {
    if (this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest) {
      console.log('WILL REDIRECT: ', this.redirectUrl);
      this.authService.loginRedirect({
        redirectStartPage: this.redirectUrl,
        ...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest,
      } as RedirectRequest);
    } else {
      this.authService.loginRedirect();
    }
  }
}
```